# this is a android with kotlin project runtime error

Tags: android, kotlin, concatenation, runtime, settext

tvPro.text = "$mCurrentPosition" + "/" + proBar.max //code

Do not concatenate text displayed with `setText`. Use resource string with placeholders. //error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a warning not an error. AS is warning you not to concatenate strings like that. Anyways, the whole idea of the $ is that you don't need to use +. Try:

```
tvPro.text = "$mCurrentPosition / ${proBar.max}"
```